# Is Google Play Music the same as the stock Android Music App?

Tags: music, google-play-music

Is [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) (formerly Google Music) the same app as the stock Android Music app?

I have a Nexus S running Android 2.3.6. I live in a country, Italy, where the Google Play Music service is not yet available. Some time ago, due to an Android Market glitch, then Google Music appeared among the apps installed on my phone.

The Market kept nagging me to update to the latest versions, which always failed because the app is not installed and I can't install it from the Market in my country. Before uninstalling the Google Play Music app entry, I'd like to make sure it's not the same as the stock Music app, which I instead want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's a completely different service.

In fact, it's a cloud service with an Android app; whereas the Music app is simply a local music app.

Answer (score 0):

Google (Play) Music is a separate and quite different app from the stock Music app that comes pre-loaded on most Android handsets.  It is possible to have both installed alongside each other without any issues.  Uninstalling Google Play Music should not in any way impact the stock Music app.

Comment: Interestingly, I am unable to uninstall Google Play Music. The Play Store (formerly Market) entry for this app under My Apps only includes the buttons Open and Update, but not Uninstall. And the app is not listed under Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications, not even in the All tab.