# Wrong playlist order in Google Play Music app

Tags: google-play-music

I use the [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) app to play locally stored music on my Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.3. I have created some playlists in standard extended m3u format on my computer and transferred them to my phone.

The problem is that the app plays some of the songs in the wrong order.  Most songs are shown and played in the right order, but about ten percent are in no particular order.

Shuffle is off (the symbol is black rather than orange).

The playlist is constructed properly and works without issue on winamp on my phone and numerous apps on my computer. The music files are all properly tagged and stored in `/sdcard/Music/artist/album/song`.  Playlists are stored in `/sdcard/Music`.

I don't use any of the cloud features of the player.

I've tried deleting all music and rescanning, as well as clearing the media storage data, but that does not help.

BTW, according to [Is Google Play Music the same as the stock Android Music App?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20380/is-google-play-music-the-same-as-the-stock-android-music-app), the Google Play Music app is not the same as the stock Android music app, but I can't find the 4.3 stock Android music app. Is that post still true?

Any ideas for getting the app to play playlists in the correct order?

EDIT: I used a [Playlist backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ssi.playlistbackup) app to export the Google Play Music version of a playlist and compared it to the text of the m3u file present on the phone that GPM purported to read. This confirmed that GPM messed up the order of the tracks on the playlist.

Comment: That linked question is out of date now. Back then it was true, but Google Play Music is now the only music player included in stock Android, the standalone player isn't included any more.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this happens on very large playlists (>100 files). I use doubleTwist to sync and my large playlist is always out of order in GPM no matter what I try. Fortunately the dT music player doesn't appear to use the playlist after creating it; but instead uses its own database for the order.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for say 50-75 files and when i reported to the Developer at the bottom they asked me to simply update the app.Later in the next release this bug appeared again so i simply disabled the app and went for another [player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) or another [player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock).

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time downloading different "recommended" players and eventually found [GoneMad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gonemad.gmmp) which has a 14 day trial and it ordered my tracks correctly.
OK there is a price to pay after the trial but it's worth £3.12 to get the play order correct.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on an album by deleting it from my Pixel 2. Then on my PC, I opened the album's folder in Foobar 2000, selected all tracks, right click --> tagging --> get tags from freedb.

Then I re-copied it to my Pixel 2 and the order was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I found this;
[Google Play Music displaying songs out of order? Here's how to fix it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2rpdpr/google_play_music_displaying_songs_out_of_order/)

All the tracks needed a disc number. It seems to work on my Samsung Galaxy at the moment.

Comment: Sorry don't bother, it didn't work. It moved some but not all.

Comment: If you find your answer does not work, you can delete it.